# Only first cell appears initially in UITableView, the rest appear after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am going crazy over this seemingly simple task that is messing up.

I have a `UItableView` with a custom cell. Inside the cell, I have only 1 label that can have different heights (depending on content)

I am using Auto Layout for that. I set the top, bottom, left, right constraints to the cell's content view. I am not setting up height and width so that it can expand depending on the device.

The weird thing is: **When I remove the bottom constraints, all cells appear, but overlap since there is no constraint to stop them.**

When I load the `UITableView`, the first comment appears fine, but the others have a height of 10px and do not appear. After scrolling, they appear normally.

Any insights or hints are appreciated,

Cheers.

EDIT:

I am using `UITableView.estimatedRowHeight` and `UITableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

But nothing changes.

Code:

UITableView Delegate ViewController:

```
   _commentsList.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
_commentsList.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
_commentsList.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Here is the IB file with the constraints ( note number of lines for label is set to 0):
[image]

Comment: See the link  1.http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: leave the 4 constraints and in `viewDidLoad` do the following: `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (where `tableView` is the name of your tableview and 44.0 and estimated value - change it to what suits you)

Comment: @AndreSlotta I am doing that. Ashok , Which part exactly should I be looking at?

Comment: and you do not have `heightforrowatindexpath` implemented, do you?

Comment: @AndreSlotta No, I do not know how to calculate the height from UILabel. But why is it that when i add the bottom constraint, the other cells shrink?

Comment: @Pacemaker could you maybe share your project to take a look whats going wrong?

Comment: @AndreSlotta It's a big project, what exactly do you think you need to see?

Comment: actually only the problematic viewcontroller in a storyboard and the viewcontrollers class of course...

Comment: aren't you using storyboards?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76437/discussion-between-pacemaker-and-andre-slotta).

Comment: Where are you setting the text for the labels? Is it in the `cellForRow` method or in another one?

Comment: Thanks all. Turns out the problem was that I didn't give the UILabel a placeholder text initially. After I put a placeholder text in the IB , everything worked fine.